# Rally Rest API .NET Toolkit Creating Defect/User Story with Tags

Tags: rally

I'm having some trouble creating a new defect or user story with a tag included. I've tried a few different ways, and typically the defect is created in Rally, but with no tags attached. From looking at the Rally API and the source code for the toolkit, it seems like the tags should be in an ArrayList. Here is my latest attempt. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
DynamicJsonObject itemToCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
itemToCreate["project"] = project["_ref"];

ArrayList tagList = new ArrayList();

DynamicJsonObject myTag = new DynamicJsonObject();
myTag["_ref"] = "/tag/1435887928";

tagList.Add(myTag);
itemToCreate["Tags"] = tagList;
CreateResult itemToCreateResult = restApi.Create(workspace["_ref"], "defect", itemToCreate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
 ArrayList tagList = new ArrayList();
 DynamicJsonObject myTag = new DynamicJsonObject();
 myTag["_ref"] = "/tag/2222";
 tagList.Add(myTag);
 myStory["Tags"] = tagList;
 updateResult = restApi.Update(createResult.Reference, myStory);
```

This code creates a user story, finds a tag based on ref and adds a tag to a story:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace Rest_v2._0_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");

            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/11111"; //replace this OID with an OID of your workspace

            //Create an item
            DynamicJsonObject myStory = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myStory["Name"] = "abcdefg11";
            CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "HierarchicalRequirement", myStory);
            DynamicJsonObject s = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference, "FormattedID");
            Console.WriteLine(s["FormattedID"]);

            myStory["Description"] = "This is my story.";
            OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(createResult.Reference, myStory);

            ArrayList tagList = new ArrayList();
            DynamicJsonObject myTag = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myTag["_ref"] = "/tag/2222";
            tagList.Add(myTag);

            //Update the item 
            myStory["Tags"] = tagList;
            updateResult = restApi.Update(createResult.Reference, myStory);
        }
    }
}
```